# I can't find the MySQL service on Bluemix

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I can't find the MySQL service on Bluemix.

My space zone is in sydney.

Answer (score 3):

The [mysql](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mysql/) service is experimental and you can find it in the [Bluemix Labs Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/labs/). If you want to use a service from the official catalog you can use [ClearDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cleardb-mysql-database/) (it is basically MySQL). However as you can see from the links above, both those services are not currently available in Sydney region. You could switch to US or UK from your Bluemix Dashboard.